# Como armazenar coordenadas GPS em uma aplicação web PHP?

Tags: php, xml, google, gps, maps

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Web que irá monitorar o deslocamento de indivíduos através do recebimento a cada 5 segundos de coordenadas GPS.

Consigo receber as coordenadas e plotar na tela com o Google Maps API, porém, necessito de uma forma de armazenar os dados para auditoria, para posteriormente verificar o caminho percorrido em determinado período de tempo.

Inicialmente pensei no MySQL, mas esse me parece um pouco dispendioso, por alto, calculo 1Gb por dispositivo, anualmente.

Também andei lendo sobre soluções orientadas a arquivos como MongoDB, Cassandra e HyperTable. Cogitei até mesmo o armazenamento em arquivo XML, com rotação e backup em arquivos compactados.

Comment: Já pensou em algum tipo de compactação ou anulação de coordenadas repetidas? Poderia colocar uma amostra de coordenadas e os campos que você precisaria salvar?

Comment: Não vejo qualquer problema em usar MySQL para esta solução. Tenho bases de dados que guardam 10 ou 20 GB por dia e funcionam bem.

Comment: Talvez fosse melhor você enviar em intervalos pequenos (10s) somente quando a diferença passasse de um certo limite, e quando fossem coordenadas dentro de um raio pré-definido da que foi enviada por último, mandasse num intervalo maior (30s, por exemplo). E ainda, no segundo caso, seria mesmo para verificar se o sinal está vivo apenas, pois você em vez de armazenar novamente, apenas atualizaria a data/hora no DB.

Comment: usa um banco como redis ou bigquery do google. são feito pra receber milhoes de dados por dia e garantir as querys rapidas

Answer (score -1):

parece um projeto muito legal, eu usaria um banco de dados mais rapido, tipo sqlite, o banco poderia estar em um server com disco ssd com I/O alto e dai faz umas api pra inserir e buscar registros desse servidor, pra alimentar a tua aplicação.

tambem faria uma forma de ter distintas bases sqlite pra cada dispositivo, e armazenaria os dados de acesso(endereço) do sqlite em uma bases qualquer, seja mysql ou postgres.

da pra faze muita coisa, de varias formar diferentes, essa foi a ideia q tive, boa sorte

Answer (score -1):

Interessante o modelo do projeto, creio que o mysql não teria problemas em salvar essa quantidade de dados, mas um banco NoSQL creio que seria uma solução mais adequada!

Reveja também esse intervalo de 5 segundos para envio das coordenadas, qual tipo de comunicação? 3G? SMS? Rádio?

Infelizmente a infraestrutura do nosso país principalmente com internet ainda é precária, lembre-se que nem sempre terá um bom sinal, e talvez o tempo de recebimento das suas mensagens pelo serviço pode demorar mais que 5 segundos, enfileirando e atrapalhando o processo de recebimento!

Tudo isso claro, dependendo do tipo de comunicação que está utilizando, e qual a real necessidade de ter esses dados a cada 5 segundos. Fiz algo do tipo, funcionou e supriu todas as necessidades com um intervalo de 30seg.

Grande abraço